# Calling SqlConnection.ClearAllPools() in Application_Start & Application_End?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, connection-pooling

We are trying to diagnose an issue that occurred in our production environment last week. Long story short, the database connection pool seemed to be full of active connections from our ASP.NET 3.5 app that would not clear, even after restarting the application pool and IIS.

The senior DBA said that because the network connections occur at the operating system level, recycling the app and IIS did not sever the actual network connections, so SQL Server left the database connections to continue running, and our app was still unable to reach the database.

In looking up ways to force a database connection pool to reset, I found the static method `SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()`, with documentation explaining what it does, but little to nothing explaining *when* to call it. It seems like calling it at the beginning of `Application_Start` and the end of `Application_End` in my global.asax.cs is a good safety measure to protect the app from poisoned connection pools, though it would of course incur a performance hit on startup/shutdown times.

Is what I've described a good practice? Is there a better one? The goal is to allow a simple app restart to reset an app's mangled connection pool without having to restart the OS or the SQL Server service, which would affect many other apps.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a process dies, all network connection are always, always, always closed immediately. That's at the TCP level. Has nothing to do with ADO.NET and goes for all applications. Kill the browser, and all downloads stop. Kill the FTP client and all connections are closed immediately.

Also, the connection pool is per process. So clearing it when starting the app is useless because the pool is empty. Clearing it at shutdown is not necessary because all connections will (gracefully) shut down any moment.

Probably, your app is not returning connections to the pool. You *must* dispose of all connections after use in all cases. If you fail to do that, dangling connections will accumulate for an indefinite amount of time.

Clearing the pool does not free up dangling connections because those appear to be in use. How could ADO.NET tell that you'll never use them again? It can't.

Look at `sys.dm_exec_connections` to see who is holding connections open. You might increase the ADO.NET pool size as a stop-gap measure. SQL Server can take over 30k connections per instance. You'll normally never saturate that.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned I am 100% sure I am wrapping every db call in a using() statement to ensure Dispose() is called even if my app blows up, as well as explicitly closing connections everywhere the moment I am done with them.

What you describe makes sense to me but the DBA led me to believe that some of this is managed at the OS level, not the process. We had 100 connections survive recycling of IIS so perhaps it was this other app we didn't suspect was involved at all. Hmmm . . . .

Comment: You can add an "App Name" parameter to your connection string to track who is connecting with the DMV. You can also see the client PID and other details there.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This DBA knows the living hell out of SQL Server but I thought he was wrong on the connection lifecycle and it sounds like you concur. Because the connections survived process recycle it seems like it really must be the other app. Per your suggestion I will add an App Name to each service's connection string so we can be 100% sure which app is at fault should this ever recur. And I won't bother with ClearAllPools.